# How to install and setup Cucumber jar files in Eclipse for WebDriver Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am fairly new to Java, eclipse, Cucumber and Selenium. I am just beginning to learn these. Overall, I am fairly new to StackoverFlow.

I got problem that I am unable to ADD any dependencies in my POM.XML in eclipse. I have saved Cucumber jvm-java, cucumber jvm-junit in my library folder

I explained clearly step by step below...

1. installed cucumber jvm-junit jar file 1.1.2 and paste it in my library
2. installed cucumber jvm-java jar file 1.1.2 and paste it in my library
3. Sikuli, selenium 2.35.0, chrome driver, IE driver also been there in library.
4. I created one Maven project
5. Added feature file for the created Maven project.
6. POM.XML is visible in my eclipse
7. I got problem here, When I Double clicked POM and clicked Dependencies tab to add dependencies for cucumber jar files.
8. And I entered Cucumber or selenium in my search field tab, then I dont see any results return.  IT'S EMPTY.

I don't know how to add these dependencies in to POM.XML. I am trying to figure out these on the internet. I didnt get what exactly I am looking. Basically, the dependencies results are not returned so I can't add to the POM and I can't continue test with Cucumber framework.

Can anyone please sort this out with clear understanding each steps, as I am fairly new to all these.

Answer (score 0):

read this link might be good for you

http://xebee.xebia.in/index.php/2014/06/04/behavior-driven-development-using-cucumber-jvm-a-java-approach/